# Kafka automaticaly cast string field to int

Tags: json, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm having a weird behavior using Kafka while sending a message with fields containing numbers as string :

```
{
   "test1": "1",
   "test2": "9000000000000000",
   "test3": "9999999999999999",
   "test4": "10000000000000000"
}
```

When I'm producing this message to my topic, Kafka transform them to Int or not depending on the value.
Here is the result after producing it in my topic :

```
{
  "test1": "1",
  "test2": "9000000000000000",
  "test3": 9999999999999999,
  "test4": 10000000000000000
}
```

test3 and test4 are converted to an Int value instead of keeping as a string.

I've tested it with a C# client but also using confluent web app.
Is there any way to avoid this automatic conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka isn't doing this. Your serialization framework is. For example, if you have a JSON model that defines the fields as Integer, rather than String, it may parse and type-convert those values for you.

Comment: I'm not using any serialization framework, even producing the message through the confluent web app is producing the same result. No schema is defined in my Kafka topic.

Comment: schema isn't relevant. Unclear what "web portal" you are referring to, since there are many available for Kafka. And yes, they all use some serialization framework since Kafka only accepts bytes, and data therefore needs (de)serializated into the topics and/or displayd in a UI.

Comment: I'm using confluent, looks like it's a bug. We didn't reproduced it on kafka without confluent. A ticket has been opened.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this. Confluent Platform is still **Apache Kafka** underneath. If you are only looking at data with a UI tool, rather than `kafka-console-consumer`, then the bug is there, or as answered, your clients (or the UI) are (de)serializing the data incorrectly.